# where is configuration.nix after install

Tags: nix, nixos

I just installed nixos using the minimal installer. I wrote up a basic configuration.nix and now when I log in as a user I can't find it in /etc/nixos/. In fact, that entire directory is empty.

What happened? How can I make incremental edits to my system and rebuild?

Comment: We'd need to see your actual installation steps to say why this happened. Whenever I've installed a NixOS system (something I do with some frequency), the file is there -- it might be missing if you saved it on the install CD's tmpfs overlay filesystem instead of on the mounted target.

Comment: That said, this isn't really on-topic here -- Stack Overflow is limited to questions about software development as such. Questions about writing code in the Nix language is definitely on-topic. NixOS (or any other Linux distro's) configuration, not so much.

Comment: Anyhow, if you _have_ a working system, you can build a new `configuration.nix` the same way you did so when booted on the live cd and assembled the first one, with `nixos-generate-config`.

Comment: The issue was not copying the config files over to the persistent directory that is later mounted at /etc/nixos

Comment: Yes, agreed, but unless you show me a video of every step you did during the installation, how am I supposed to say why that happened? When I follow the install docs, I don't have that problem, and you aren't showing what you did to make it so you _did_ have it, so how is anyone supposed to answer this (even if it were on-topic here)?